# Missing Test Status menu in Cypress framework

Tags: user-interface, automated-tests, cypress

I have a code to test iframe "Google Apps" (Top left corner of the google.com):

```
describe ('Iframe 'Google Apps' Test', () => {  
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('https://google.ru')
    cy.get(".gb_A").click()
    cy.frameLoaded("iframe[role='presentation']")           
  })

    it('Click on "YouTube', () => {
      cy.iframe().xpath("//span[text()='YouTube']").click() 
      cy.url().should('include', 'youtube.com')
```

When it is launched and the first step is taken to go to YouTube, the test status menu (usually left side) disappears and the site opens to the full page. How can i fix it to see how the other tests are complete?

GIF of error
[image]

Comment: Add the error screenshot or a GIF of your execution to debug more.

Comment: Thanks. I've add gif